# Convert binary data to image reactJS

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-mvc

Application built in ReactJS & .NET Web API

Problem: I have created `GET` API in backend for download Image and this api will get image from azure blob and return data as binary.

I get that data as api response but I want to display that as image in `<Img src="" />` tag.

How can this possible..?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the binary data then convert it into an image like this:

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${binary_data}`} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please look at my attached screenshot. It's not work for me.